# Show / Integrate Java application in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, web-part, sharepoint-addin, iframe

I have a web application with .Net and java platform. I have one task like when login in SharePoint portal we need to show some application link i.e (java or .net) and when click on link that application will open in SharePoint portal.

Suppose I click on java appliaction it will open inside the SharePoint portal using iframe or any other

Can you suggest me what I can do?

Comment: If you are on Sharepoint 2013, you should look in to Provider hosted apps (the provider hosted part here can be any web application) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179887(v=office.15).aspx#SelfHosted

Comment: can you provide sample application?

Comment: I have not written one, and it is a bit to much to ask for